# device no longer shows up on debug list

Tags: android, debugging, xamarin

I use my Android phone to debug in Xamarin. I recently published one version of my app to the Play Store, so I changed the build configuration to Release beforehand.

After publishing, I changed it back to debug, but now my device no longer shows up in the list. I've made sure the configuration is set to debug and android:debuggable is true..my phone has USB debugging turned on and is being recognized by my computer, it just doesn't show up in Xamarin.

Comment: Posting device's make and model would help to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Can you adb to it ? , it happened to me with a x86 vm, it didn't want to show up until I explicitly connected adb on cmd line to the device (Disclaimer: I'm using starter edition, so NO idea if configuration changes or deployment may have an effect on that)

Answer (score 0):

Did you install new software on your phone or laptop? New drivers? It happens allot to me too, that xamarin fails to detect my devices. Usually a pc reboot will do the trick. If not, and you are sure that your phone's settings are correct, i would suggest re-installing the newest usb drivers for your phone on your pc.